# How to migrate SCCM and SCOM's databases from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, migration, sccm, scom

I need to migrate databases (including reporting services) applications System Center Operations Manager and System Center Configuration Manager to a single SQL Server 2008. Currently each of the servers has a dedicated SQL 2005 Instance.

I'm looking for a step by step walkthough for each of these applications.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's Documentation:

[How to move a site database in SCCM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb680707.aspx)
You must have [SCCM 2007 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5aae62e8-4b7f-4af7-be01-aefaa4bf059a&displaylang=en) installed with Hotfix [KB955262](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955262) to use SQL 2008.

[For SCOM you must have SP2 installed](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd362729.aspx).
Then you get to move the three databases separately: [Warehouse](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc540368.aspx), [Database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc540384.aspx), and [Reporting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc540369.aspx).